# changes in Controller not detected in ModelBehavior

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I've been tasked to make some changes in a big *CakePHP* app, I'm trying to change a value in `$this->data` holds data from a form.

***Controller***

```
// $this->data['key'] is true coming from a form.
...
if(a) {
    $this->data['key'] = false;
}
$this->Model->Calculate();
```

***ModelBehavior***

```
function calculate(&$Model) {
    log($Model->data['key']);
}
// prints true;
```

I can't understand why the value of `$Model->data['key']` is `true`, it was my understanding that `$this->data` gets passed as `$Model` in a *ModelBehavior*. what am I missing please? I'm very new to *PHP* and *CakePHP*.

Comment: Still working on 1.3 in the age of 4.x is dangerous. However you can check from if the behavior is attached to the modal and if you can add more code then it can help investigate the matter.

Answer (score 0):

Usually `Model::data` is set by the find methods of the model or `Model::set()`.

Call `$this->ModelName->set($this->data)` in your controller before invoking the calculation. Make sure that the structure of `$this->data` complies with the CakePHP conventions.